# JTable : Unexpected behavior when clicking under the last item

Tags: java, swing, jtable

**Please look at the picture first : it is not normal that the five last rows appear. It is when I clicked on the gray empty area that they appeared.**

I've made a program that lists groceries.

At the launch of the program, the `JTable` displays the entire database and then I let the user select what he wants to see.

Here for example, I selected all the groceries made at "Carrefour" and there is a total of 7 items in the list. It displays normally.

But when I go and click in the gray area under the last item, the JTable has an unexpected behavior shown on the image below (it shows other date of the database as if the whole database was displayed like in the launching). The same happens when I resize the frame or try to ordre the different columns.

I've made my research and can not find any solution to this problem.

**BEFORE CLICKING**

[image: JTableBeforeClicking]

**AFTER CLICKING**

[image: JTable Problem]

Here is the portion of the code concerning the creation of the JTable :

```
private void tableCreation(String query) {
    // Random database queries I don't display for the sake of clarity

        excel = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        excel.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    tablePanel.removeAll();
    this.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(tablePanel.add(excel)), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.revalidate();
}
```

And here is the part of the code concerning the research and thus the modifying of the JTable :

```
class SearchListener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    // Random query construction with the e.getText() method

    if (!column.equals("prix") && !column.equals("num_id")){
            query = "select * from products where " + column + " like '%" + searchText.getText().toUpperCase().trim() + "%'";
        }else{
            query = "select * from products where " + column + " = '" + searchText.getText().toUpperCase().trim() + "'";
        }

    }else{
        query = "select * from products";
    }
        tableCreation(query);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1 :**

I have tried to put the JTable directly on the JPanel without using a JScrollPane, it did not work out.

I also tried to not display the entire database at the launch of the program but when I'm doing the first query, the problem is the same. It either displays gray rows, or it displays the data from the last query when I click a random row.

I know the problem is not coming from the query I'm using because the wanted data is correctly displayed.

I'm really lost and could not imagine where it could come from.

For info : I'm using a JFrame with different JPanel's on it. On one of them, I added the JScrollPane on which I put my JTable.

**EDIT 2 :**

I posted the whole code [**here**](http://www.codesend.com/view/e85dc32b75ee9603c8c760589506e718/) to anyone wanting to have the details. It is contained in one class only so it is easy to read.

---

Whole code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class FrameFC extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FrameFC fr = new FrameFC();
    }

    /*Main Frame Creation*/

    private JSplitPane split;
    private Font f = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15);
    private JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();

    /*Panel Creation*/
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

    private JPanel westPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel();

    private JPanel addPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel searchPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel removePanel = new JPanel();

    private int screenHeight = (int) (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight());
    private int screenWidth = (int) (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth());

    private JButton buttonAdd = new JButton("Ajouter"),
                    buttonSearch = new JButton("Rechercher"),
                    buttonRemove = new JButton("Supprimer");

    private JTextField  nomP = new JTextField(),
                        cat = new JTextField(),
                        mag = new JTextField(),
                        prix = new JTextField(),
                        dateAchat = new JTextField(),
                        codemag = new JTextField(),
                        removeText = new JTextField();

    private JTextField searchText = new JTextField();

    private String[] tabCat = {"ID", "Nom Produit", "Categorie", "Magasin", "Prix", "Date (JJ/MM/AAAA)", "Code Magasin"};

    private JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(tabCat);

    /*Table Creation*/
    private JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();
    private JTable excel = new JTable();
    private String query = "select * from products order by num_id";

    public FrameFC(){
        this.setTitle("Gestionnaire de produits");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panelCreation();
        tableCreation(query);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    class AjouterListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (nomP.getText().equals("") ||
                    cat.getText().equals("") ||
                    mag.getText().equals("") ||
                    prix.getText().equals("") ||
                    dateAchat.getText().equals("")){

            }else{
                String nomps, cats, mags, prixs, dates;
                nomps = nomP.getText();
                cats = cat.getText();
                mags = mag.getText();
                prixs = prix.getText();
                dates = dateAchat.getText();

                query = "insert into products "
                        + "(nom_produit, cat, mag, prix, date_achat, code_magasin)"
                        + " values ("
                        + "'" + nomps + "', '" + cats
                        + "', '" + mags + "', " + prixs
                        + ", '" + dates + "', '" + codemag.getText() + "');";

                Statement state;
                ResultSet res;
                try {
                    state = ConnectPostGRESql.getInstance("postgres").createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                    res = state.executeQuery(query);
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    System.out.println(nomps + " ajouté avec succès.");
                }

                query = "select * from products";
                tableCreation(query);
                nomP.setText("");
                cat.setText("");
                prix.setText("");

            }
        }
    }

    class SearchListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String column;

            if (!searchText.getText().equals("")){

            switch (String.valueOf(combo.getSelectedItem()))
            {
            case "ID":
                column = "num_id";
                break;
            case "Nom Produit":
                column = "nom_produit";
                break;
            case "Categorie":
                column = "cat";
                break;
            case "Magasin":
                column = "mag";
                break;
            case "Prix":
                column = "prix";
                break;
            case "Code Magasin":
                column = "code_magasin";
                break;
            default:
                column = "date_achat";
                break;
            }
            if (!column.equals("prix") && !column.equals("num_id")){
                query = "select * from products where " + column + " like '%" + searchText.getText().toUpperCase().trim() + "%'";
            }else{
                query = "select * from products where " + column + " = '" + searchText.getText().toUpperCase().trim() + "'";
            }

        }else{
            query = "select * from products";
        }
            tableCreation(query);
        }
    }

    class RemoveListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!removeText.getText().equals("")){
                Statement state;
                ResultSet res;
                try {
                    state = ConnectPostGRESql.getInstance("postgres").createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                    res = state.executeQuery("delete from products where num_id = " + removeText.getText());
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    System.out.println("Entrée supprimée avec succès.");
                }
            }
            tableCreation("select * from products");

        }
    }

    private void tableCreation(String query) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Statement state = ConnectPostGRESql.getInstance("postgres").createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            ResultSet res = state.executeQuery(query);

            ResultSetMetaData meta = res.getMetaData();

            Object[] columnNames = new Object[meta.getColumnCount()];

            for (int i = 1; i<=meta.getColumnCount();i++){
                columnNames[i-1] = meta.getColumnName(i);
            }

            res.last();

            Object[][] rowData = new Object[res.getRow()][meta.getColumnCount()];

            res.beforeFirst();

            int j = 1;

            while (res.next()){
                for (int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++){
                    if (i == 1){
                        int nombredez = 4 - String.valueOf(res.getInt(i)).length();
                        String nombredezString = "";
                        for (int n = 0; n < nombredez;n++){
                            nombredezString += "0";
                        }
                        rowData[j-1][i-1] = nombredezString + String.valueOf(res.getObject(i));
                    }
                    else{
                        rowData[j-1][i-1] = res.getObject(i);
                    }
                }
                j++;
            }

            res.close();
            state.close();

            excel = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
            excel.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tablePanel.removeAll();
        this.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(tablePanel.add(excel)), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.revalidate();
    }

    private void panelCreation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        /*Panel Add (West)*/
        addPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,2));

        addPanel.add(new JLabel("Entrez le nom du produit :"));
        addPanel.add(nomP);
        addPanel.add(new JLabel("Entrez la catégorie :"));
        addPanel.add(cat);
        addPanel.add(new JLabel("Entrez le magasin :"));
        addPanel.add(mag);
        addPanel.add(new JLabel("Entrez le prix :"));
        addPanel.add(prix);
        addPanel.add(new JLabel("Entrez la date :"));
        addPanel.add(dateAchat);
        addPanel.add(new JLabel("Entrez le code magasin"));
        addPanel.add(codemag);
        addPanel.add(new JLabel());

        buttonAdd.addActionListener(new AjouterListener());
        addPanel.add(buttonAdd);

        addPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Ajouter"));
        addPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(949, 360));

        /*Panel Search (North-East)*/
        searchPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

        searchPanel.add(combo);
        searchPanel.add(searchText);
        searchPanel.add(new JLabel());

        buttonSearch.addActionListener(new SearchListener());
        searchPanel.add(buttonSearch);

        searchPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Rechercher"));
        searchPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(949, 180));

        /*Panel Remove (South-East)*/
        removePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

        removePanel.add(new JLabel("Entrez le numero d'identifiant : "));
        removePanel.add(removeText);
        removePanel.add(new JLabel());

        buttonRemove.addActionListener(new RemoveListener());
        removePanel.add(buttonRemove);

        removePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Supprimer"));
        removePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(949, 180));

        /*MainPanel on Frame*/
        westPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 2));
        westPanel.add(addPanel);

        eastPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        eastPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 2));

        eastPanel.add(searchPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        eastPanel.add(removePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        mainPanel.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        mainPanel.add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        this.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(mainPanel), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

}
```

Comment: "the JTable has an unexpected behavior" - and that unexpected behaviour is...?

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited it but in two words, when clicking under, it shows data from the launcing of the program when the whole database was displayed. I added a picture to my explanation.

Comment: Well what diagnostics have you used so far to work out what's going on? Have you put breakpoints in the code to look at what query is being executed? You should be able to narrow this question down considerably and provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. (See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: do you mean you don't want all columns of the database? so, you have used `select *` statement there.

Comment: are you getting any error message also? check your console out.

Comment: @ChannaJayamuni Hi Channa, no it is not a query problem at all. Actually, the query is correct and the data displayed on the image on the first 7 rows is OK. But as you see, other data appear underneath when I clicked on the empty area under the JTable data.. That is actually a problem. I think it is GUI

Comment: yes, it could happen when database have null values. most commonly you are getting stacktrace when renderring null values in the jtable.

Comment: @ChannaJayamuni There's no stacktrace appearing on the console

Comment: Are you overriding `public void paint(Graphics g)` or `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` or fiddling with GUI graphics in any way? If so, are you taking care to call the super's painting method within your override? I agree with @JonSkeet, that your best bet for getting quick, correct help is to create and post your [mcve] (please check out the link). The key is that before solving a problem you will need to isolate and identify it first.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Hi Hovercraft, none of that. I do use the revalidate method from the JFrame though. Ok I'll check that and try to modify the question.

Comment: you have removed the code where generate table data array. can you re add it. it seems some of columns not returned data to the array

Comment: @ChannaJayamuni I'm planning to modify my question but I posted a link to the entire code if you want to check it out.

Comment: i have checked the code, but it seems everything ok. is there any method to see when it is running live. do you have teamviewer.

Comment: One small thing -- after calling `revalidate()`, also call `repaint()`.

Comment: Also, rather than creating and adding new JTables and JScrollPanes, it's often easier to simply leave a single JTable in the GUI and simply update its model or give it a new model, if the table changes completely.

Comment: Also, get rid of tablePanel. Instead add the JTable directly to the JScrollPane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem appears to be caused by adding a new JScrollPane with JTable without removing the prior JScrollPane.

For instance, try running the code below

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FrameFC extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FrameFC();
    }

    private Random random = new Random();    
    private JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();

    private JTable excel = new JTable();
    private JScrollPane currentScrollPane = null;

    public FrameFC() {
        this.setTitle("Gestionnaire de produits");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        northPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Change Table") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                tableCreation();
            }
        }));

        add(northPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        tableCreation();
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void tableCreation() {
        String[] columnNames = {"A", "B", "C"};

        int rowCount = random.nextInt(10) +3;
        Object[][] rowData = new Object[rowCount][columnNames.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rowData[i].length; j++) {
                rowData[i][j] = "" + random.nextInt(100) + 50;
            }
        }

        excel = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        excel.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

        if (currentScrollPane != null) {
            // remove(currentScrollPane);   // ******* here ******
        }
        currentScrollPane = new JScrollPane(excel);

        add(currentScrollPane);
        this.revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

}
```

with and without this line commented:

```
// remove(currentScrollPane);   // ******* here ******
```

If it is not in place, you may see side effects from the retained JScrollPane.

A better solution however is as I mentioned in my comments: don't swap components, but instead swap the model in the JTable. Create a DefaultTableModel with the desired data and set your JTable's model by calling `setModel(...)` on it. This is much cleaner and much safer.

Note also my attempts above to take your code and remove all bits not related to your problem, including any and all SQL code as well as components and listeners not related to the problem. Please consider doing this yourself in your attempts to debug and in your questions on this site.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PanelFC extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {"A", "B", "C"};
    private Random random = new Random();    
    private JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();    
    private JTable excel = new JTable(modelCreation());

    public PanelFC() {
        northPanel.add(new JButton(new CreateModelAction("Create Model")));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(northPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(new JScrollPane(excel), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private TableModel modelCreation() {
        // your code will take some parameter, and using database query 
        // result, create the table model
        // Also, all database code should be called in a background thread
        int rowCount = random.nextInt(10) +3;
        Object[][] rowData = new Object[rowCount][COLUMN_NAMES.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rowData[i].length; j++) {
                rowData[i][j] = "" + random.nextInt(100) + 50;
            }
        }        
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, COLUMN_NAMES);
        return model;
    }

    private class CreateModelAction extends AbstractAction {
        public CreateModelAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            excel.setModel(modelCreation());
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        PanelFC mainPanel = new PanelFC();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PanelFC");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, if you know how long I've been looking to resolve this problem. I'm really grateful HoverCraft. Thank you very much, it works perfectly.

Comment: @YassinHH: You're welcome -- please see edit. Best solution: create the TableModel from the database data. Also as per comments, you should strive to put the database access data into a background thread. Also, re-read the [mcve] link. I created my MCVE here to solve this problem, but in the future, the onus of effort to create and post these should be on the question asker, not the volunteer question solver.

Comment: I've read it and was willing to edit the question after recreating the whole problem of course... Thanks for the advice and thanks again for the help :)